# Automatizar ventana modal?

Tags: javascript, html, modal, popup, ventana

la verdad que estoy bastante verde con este tema, por eso les pido algo de ayuda ... tengo el siguiente codigo que necesito que cargue de forma automatica al ingresar a un sitio, del sitio donde consegui el modal esta para activarlo de forma manual y no me sirve ...

Desde ya muchas gracias, espero puedan ayudarme!!
perdon por la desprolijidad pero es la primera vea que usa la pagina y todavia no la conozco bien.

Creo que lo que describo esta mas que bien, no se por que no me deja terminar la edicion de la pagina ...

```html
<h1></h1>
<a href="https://escss.blogspot.com/2016/09/ventana-modal-javascript-puro.html"></a>
<br>

<script>
// función aparte para no complicar el código
function metaventana() {
  jmgModal('ventana2',{
    title: 'Sub-ventana',
    width: 300,
    height: 20,
        content: 'Contenido de la sub-ventana'});
}
</script>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
 jmgModal('miventana', {
    title: 'La Real',
    width: 550,
    height: 70,
    content: '<img src=\'https://agencialareal.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/construccion.jpg\'>'    
}); }
function jmgModal(id, data, ok, cancel, input) {
 data=data || {};
 id="modal-"+id;
 if (document.getElementById(id)==null) {
  var d=document.createElement("div");
  d.className="jmgmodal";
  d.id=id;
  var p=document.createElement("div");
  p.className="panel";
  var t=document.createElement("div");
  t.className="title";
  var cl=document.createElement("div");
  cl.className="close";
  cl.innerHTML='×';
  cl.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var dTop=this.parentNode.parentNode;
   dTop.classList.remove("visible");
   dTop.querySelector(".panel .content").innerHTML='';
  });
  var ct=document.createElement("div");
  ct.className="content";
  var f=document.createElement("div");
  f.className="footer";
  p.appendChild(t);p.appendChild(cl);p.appendChild(ct);p.appendChild(f);
  d.appendChild(p);
  document.body.appendChild(d);
 }
 var mod=document.getElementById(id),
 p=mod.querySelector(".panel"),
 t=mod.querySelector(".panel .title"),
 ct=mod.querySelector(".panel .content"),
 f=mod.querySelector(".panel .footer");
 if (f==null) {
  mod.classList.remove("nofooter");
  var f=document.createElement("div");
  f.className="footer";
  p.appendChild(f);
 }
 t.innerHTML=data.title || '';
 ct.innerHTML=data.content || '';
 f.innerHTML='';
 if (!isNaN(data.width)) p.style.maxWidth=data.width+'px';
 if (!isNaN(data.height)) p.style.maxHeight=data.height+'vh';
 if (ok && ok.length>1) {
  var param={value:null};
  if (input && input.length>0) {
   var ph=document.createElement("p");
   ph.className="action";
   var txt=document.createElement("input");
   txt.className="action";
   txt.setAttribute("placeholder",input[0]);
   txt.addEventListener('keydown',function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode==13 || ev.key=="Enter") {
     ev.preventDefault();
     mod.classList.remove("visible");
     ok[1](param.value);
    }
   });
   ph.appendChild(txt); ct.appendChild(ph);
   param=ct.querySelector("p.action > input.action");
   setTimeout(function(){
    param.focus();
   },100);
  }
  var bOk=document.createElement("button");
  bOk.className="action";
  bOk.innerHTML=ok[0];
  bOk.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   mod.classList.remove("visible");
   ok[1](param.value);
  });
  f.appendChild(bOk);
 }
 if (cancel && cancel.length>1) {
  var bCancel=document.createElement("button");
  bCancel.className="action";
  bCancel.innerHTML=cancel[0];
  bCancel.addEventListener('click',function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   mod.classList.remove("visible");
   cancel[1]();
  });
  f.appendChild(bCancel);
 }
 if (f.innerHTML=='') {
  p.removeChild(f);
  mod.classList.add("nofooter");
 }
 setTimeout(function(){
  mod.classList.add("visible");
 },50);
}
```

```css
.jmgmodal {
position: fixed; margin: auto;
top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
box-sizing: content-box;
visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;
transition: all .12s; z-index: 99;
}
.jmgmodal.visible {
visibility: visible; opacity: 1;
}
.jmgmodal * {box-sizing: inherit}
.jmgmodal .panel {
position: absolute; margin: auto;
top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
max-width: 600px; max-height: 70vh;
background: #fff; border-radius: 10px;
color: #000; padding: 50px 0;
transform: translateY(-25%);
transition: all .12s;
}
.jmgmodal.nofooter .panel {
padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.jmgmodal.visible .panel {
transform: none;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .title {
position: absolute; top: 0;
width: 100%; height: 50px;
line-height: 50px; background: inherit;
font-weight: bolder; padding: 0 2em;
box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .close {
position: absolute; top: .25em; right: .75em;
cursor: pointer; font-size: 25px;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content {
max-height: 100%; overflow: auto;
padding: 1em; box-sizing: border-box;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content iframe:only-child {
border: 0; width: 100%;
height: 100%; height: 80vh;
min-height: 200px;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .content img:only-child {
width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer {
position: absolute; bottom: 0;
width: 100%; height: 50px;
line-height: 50px; background: inherit;
font-weight: bolder; padding: 0 2em;
box-shadow: 2px 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
text-align: right;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer .action {
border-radius: 10px; color: #000;
background: #fff; border: 0;
min-width: 80px; min-height: 35px;
font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 20px;
transition: all .12s;
}
.jmgmodal .panel .footer .action:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* estilos del pen, ornamentales */
html {
  background: #f1c40f;
  margin: 0 2em;
  font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
}
button {
  border: solid 2px #d35400;
  background: orange;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: .2em .5em;
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  transition: all .5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  background: #d35400;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<a href="https://escss.blogspot.com/2016/09/ventana-modal-javascript-puro.html"></a>
<br>
<button onclick="jmgModal('miventana',{
    title: 'Ventana modal',
    width: 100,
    height: 20,
        content: '<img src=\'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/166051553/favicon-escss/mstile-144x144.png\'>'});"
        >Abrir modal con una imagen</button>
<script>
// función aparte para no complicar el código
function metaventana() {
  jmgModal('ventana2',{
    title: 'Sub-ventana',
    width: 300,
    height: 20,
        content: 'Contenido de la sub-ventana'});
}
</script>
```

```html
<h1>jmgModal</h1>
<a href="https://escss.blogspot.com/2016/09/ventana-modal-javascript-puro.html">More information</a>
<br>

<button onclick="jmgModal('miventana',{
    title: 'La Real',
    width: 550,
    height: 70,
        content: '<img src=\'https://agencialareal.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/construccion.jpg\'>'});"
        >Abrir modal con una imagen</button>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto para poderte ayudar

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour] para que sepas el uso del sitio. Tu pregunta no es nada clara. Por favor copia y pega el código de lo que hayas intentado por tu cuenta. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que se ejecute la función nada mas cargar la página en la que quieres que se vea debes hacer uso de la función window.onload de JavasScript poniendo una llamada a la ventana dentro de esa función, quedaría una cosa así:

```
window.onload = function () {
jmgModal('miventana', {
    title: 'La Real',
    width: 550,
    height: 70,
    content: '<img src=\'https://agencialareal.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/construccion.jpg\'>'
}); "}
```

Con esto se ejecuta una sola vez al cargar la página.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107471/discussion-on-answer-by-jose-automatizar-ventana-modal).

Comment: Hola. Alvaro....tengo una duda,,,,¿como creo un chat con otro usuario para resolver otro problema que se va a alargar tanto como este o mas?

Comment: Es algo automático. Después de unos cuantos mensajes, debería aparecerte una notificación preguntando si deseas continuar la conversación en el chat. Aunque no sé si los usuarios deben tener una reputación mínima para que aparezca (pero creo que no).

Comment: Pues no me sale y se me está alargando la conversación, otra vez.